# VisualEditor on MediaWiki 1.36.1 results in Parsoid/RESTBase server "Couldn't connect to server" on Docker

Tags: wikimedia, visual-editor

I am using Mediawiki 1.36.1 which, according the [VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor) page, contains VisualEditor so I do not need to install it before enabling it. Furthermore, Parsoid is not required because MediaWiki >=1.35 is being used.

As per the documentation, I have added the following line to my `LocalSettings.php`:

```
wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' );
```

I have restarted my server and editing any page results in:

> Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server: (curl error: 7) Couldn't connect to server

This is confusing because:

- First, the [VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor) page states that Parsoid is not required because MediaWiki >=1.35 is being used.
- Second, it is not clear what server we're trying to connect to; why we're trying to connect to a server (we're just trying to edit some text).

It should be noted that my instance of MediaWiki is on Docker, so from my host machine, I can access MediaWiki from outside the container at http://0.0.0.0:8080, but http://0.0.0.0:8080 is not accessible from within the container.

I suspect that the `requestRestbase()` function in [includes/ApiParsoidTrait.php](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-VisualEditor/blob/c93638db36a6df322cedd45c7b2d40ddcc21e7d0/includes/ApiParsoidTrait.php#L118-L148) attempts, for some reason, to contact itself at `http://0.0.0.0:8080` (it can't), and results in an error.

Why is VisualEditor trying to do this? And how to get around this using Docker?